MIT-BIH and ECG-ID for ECG Authentication System
Both the MIT-BIH and ECG-ID data files are stored in the Waveform Database (WFDB)
file format. The record_name.dat file formats are binary files containing samples of
digitized signals.
So, can I combine both datasets into my DL model knowing that they have different sampling frequency ?
Thank you in advance
